# JQuery Remove all content inside a specified Div (Facebook Tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this:

```
$('#myLink').click(function () {
    $('#MainDIV').empty();
});
```

Where:

```
<div id="MainDIV">
    <fb:like href="somelinketc">....</fb:like>
</div>
```

I need everything inside `<div id="MainDIV">` to disappear but I'm checking firefox and it's all still there.

Comment: How are you checking firefox? You see it in the browser? You did view source? Inspected with firebug?

Comment: Looking at http://jsfiddle.net/8gMyB/ on FF12 `empty()` seems to properly work. Your js console reports any error?

Comment: Could it be a timing issue? As in, you're trying to empty the `div` before Facebook has populated it.

Comment: Yes, I just need to contents to be deleted like I would do using Firebug (firefox). There seems to be problems removing <fb:like ...facebook tags :o/

Comment: I know it's not a timing issue because I can see the code because I click the div to remove it but the content is not removed

Answer (score 2):

Try it in this way.

`$(document).ready(function(){`

```
$('#myLink').click(function(){

document.getElementById('MainDIV').innerHTML="";
});
});
```

I think this is an easy way to overwrite the existing data in the element in which you want to  make it disappear or change the contents according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your .click() function. It should end with the parenthesis like this:

```
});
```

and not like this:

```
)};
```

Should fix it.

Comment: Sorry, that was my writing it ... mistype

Comment: Well, it does works in jsfiddle. You should check for js erros.

Answer (score 1):

You should be preventing the click action of the link with [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('#myLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#MainDIV').empty();
});
```

Also I am not sure but your post above has a typo. `)}` should be `})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#MainDIV").html('');
```

That'll clear all the contents of the div.

Comment: Yes, but `empty()` also does this.

Comment: @VisioN , yes it does. empty() removes the element itself, whereas html('') only removes the contents.
http://jsfiddle.net/vZUuU/5/  . I don't understand why the downvote though.

Comment: you are not right. `empty` removes all child nodes (including text nodes) from the element. It **does not** remove the element itself.

Comment: @VisioN , if you please look at the JSFiddle demo, you can clearly see what I'm talking about.

Comment: `empty` and `remove` are different jQuery methods.

Comment: @VisioN , extremely sorry about that, somehow instead of "empty()", "remove()" was getting into my mind !

Answer (score -4):

```
$('#myLink').click(function () {
    $('#MainDIV').hide(1);
)};
```

Comment: he needs to remove the inner contents of the div